# "Has been" versus "was" for a past event

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, past-tense

In a goodbye email one of my colleagues wrote the below sentence. He has used *has also been*, which I feel is incorrect. He was talking about a past event. According to me he should use *was* instead of *has been*.

> During this time, the world, especially ours has also been rapidly changing with the advent of new technologies, SMAC, customer dynamics and expectations.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If he says "this time" and not "that time", it feels like he is talking about something close to now, I don't see a problem with the present perfect construction. What does "this time" refer to?

Comment: By the way, I notice that you have asked a number of questions but so far have not accepted any of the answers. If you find an answer helpful, it is a good idea to do this. That way we will know that we have been able to help. Here is how it is done: http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: the sentence is ungrammatical to me.

Comment: Maulik V as per my knowleadge also it is ungrammatical. Because he was talking about past tense. and the sentence construction is in Past perfect continuous. Sentence suggesting that chenges are started somewhere in past continue and still continue.

Comment: The tense in the sentence you are giving is present. PRESENT perfect continuous. If he was talking about past TIME, then he should have also written "that time". Can you provide some more context? Does "this time" refer to the time he worked for the company?

Comment: Yes Fluffy "this time" refer to the time he worked for the company.

Comment: If he is talking about a past time that he has specifically mentioned, I would say he should have said "that time" and "was changing". But the present tense is also acceptable, think about "It has been a pleasure working with you", which you say just after the work has been completed.

Answer (score 1):

You said it is a goodbye email, so for him, he is talking about an era that is over, a chapter closed for him now (perfect tense).

So the use of perfect tense is very reasonable imho.

Although use of 'was' will also be correct grammatically but this construction is more expressive for his situation.

Comment: It is actually the present perfect continuous tense.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that the action he is describing started in the past and is still happening now (and may or may not continue into the future.)

This is the perfect situation for present perfect continuous tense.